# KeyListener in JPanel doesn't recive any key events

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I'm makiing a game and when I was introduciing a user input I came across this problem. I add a KeyListener to JPanel but it doesn't work at all. The program is made of JPanel (GameWindow) inside a JFrame(WindowManager). Game is started in GameLoop object which immplements Runnable. Level contains all the information how the map look like. I read that KeyListener works if the Component is focusable so I checked if the panel is focusable and the program  returned true. Maybe it is a thread issue but i dont know why.

```
public class GameWindow extends JPanel {

   private Level level;
   private GameLoop gameLoop;
   private LevelLoader levelLoader = new LevelLoader();
   private WindowManager windowParent; // A JFrame


public GameWindow(WindowManager windowParent){
    super();
    this.windowParent = windowParent;
    setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    gameLoop = new GameLoop(this);
    level = levelLoader.loadLevel(1);
    setFocusable(true);
    requestFocusInWindow();
    addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            System.out.println("typed");
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            System.out.println("pressed");
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            System.out.println("released");
        }
    });
    start();
}

private  void start(){
    Thread thread = new Thread(gameLoop);
    thread.start();
}

@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(600, 600);
}


@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D graphics2D = (Graphics2D) g;
    graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    level.paintLevel(g,getSize());
}
```

}

Comment: This question is asked daily it seems. Please search the forum first before asking. The solution is to use [Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html). I just used search keywords like "keylistener jpanel" to find other questions on this topic with solutions. What keywords did you use?

Comment: By the way you can only request focus on a visible component. So requesting focus in the constructor does nothing since the component hasn't been added to a visible frame yet.

Comment: I searched for solution but i didnt find the one that solves my problem. I just tried Key Bindings but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Anyway i just request a focus not in constructor and it helped so thank you a lot , becouse i didn't know that the i need to add to frame first

Answer (score -1):

Problem solved i need to request for focus after the JPanel is added to JFrame and become visible.

Comment: (1-) No the problem is not solved. The proper solution is to use Key Bindings. `I just tried Key Bindings but it still doesn't work.` - then you did it wrong!!! Key bindings will work.